# delphi convert microsoft binary to ieee (8bits)

Tags: delphi, ieee-754

Somebody has the code to convert from old MSB to ieee (delphi real)?

In google I've only founded the 4bit conversion, but not for 8bits:

```
function MBF2IEEE(MBFVal: Single): Single;
var
   Output: array[1..4] of byte;
   Value: Single absolute Output;
//   Sign: byte;
   LSB: Byte;
begin
   try
      Output[4] := TInput(MBFVal)[4];
      { if value is non-zero, do some bit shuffling }
      if Output[4] > 2 then begin
         Output[3] := TInput(MBFVal)[3];
         Output[2] := TInput(MBFVal)[2];
         Output[1] := TInput(MBFVal)[1];
         Output[4] := Output[4] - $02;
         LSB := Output[4] and $01;
         Output[4] := (Output[4] shr 1) or (Output[3] and $80);
         if LSB = 0 then
            Output[3] := Output[3] and $7f
         else
            Output[3] := Output[3] or $80;
      { else return 0 }
      end else begin
         Output[1] := 0;
         Output[2] := 0;
         Output[3] := 0;
         Output[4] := 0;
      end;
      Result := Value;
   except
      Output[1] := 0;
      Output[2] := 0;
      Output[3] := 0;
      Output[4] := 0;
   end;
end;
```

(from this page
http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Pascal/Delphi/Q_20245266.html)

Thanks!

Comment: Do you a link that documents this 8byte MSB format?

Comment: Sure, still I believe someone already have done this in Delphi..

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/35826

http://www.elchabon.com/2010/07/mbfmicrosoft-binary-format-to-ieee-convertion/

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766023/convert-mbf-double-to-ieee

Comment: I asked for the link so that the rest of us could catch up with what MSB is. With some good references I'm sure someone can knock together code to do the conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working with it, converting doubles wasn't as easy as singles.. (exponents and mantises don't match).

Even the C code in the link doesn't works well in some cases (it might be because it was designed for a 16bit compiler? I don't know, hasn't time to fully test)..!

I've come across this asm library (it say's its free) that solved the problem (have to import it like C dlls):

http://www.microdexterity.com/demos/mbfiee32.zip

Good luck for the next one after this,